# PHP match values between 2 arrays not same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have made researches and havent fount any solutions for this yet. So final thought is come to Stackoverflow and ask the question.

I have 2 array like below:

BigArray

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => Accountancy
            [category_name_vi] => Kế toán
            [category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category_name] => Armed forces
            [category_name_vi] => Quân đội
            [category_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category_name] => Admin & Secretarial
            [category_name_vi] => Thư ký & Hành chính
            [category_id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [category_name] => Banking & Finance
            [category_name_vi] => Tài chính & Ngân hàng
            [category_id] => 4
        )
)
```

and SmallArray:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [category_id] => 2
            [jobseeker_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [category_id] => 3
            [jobseeker_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Ok, now I wanted to match each `category_id` from `SmallArray` link with respectively `category_name` from `BigArray`and the output I only need matched values between `SmallArray` and `BigArray`where `category_id` of `SmallArray` is key and `category_name` of `BigArray` is value like below:

Matched array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [2] => Armed forces                    
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [3] => Admin & Secretarial
            )
    )
```

So far, I have tried array_intersect, 2 foreach loops but no luck. Any advise would be very appreciated :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do that:

```
foreach ($smallArray as $smallKey => $smallElement) {
    foreach ($bigArray as $bigKey => $bigElement) {
        if ($bigElement['id'] == $smallElement['category_id']) {
            $smallArray[$smallKey] = array(
                $bigElement['id'] => $bigElement['category_name'],
            );
            break; // for performance and no extra looping
        }
    }
}
```

After these loops, you have what you want in `$smallArray`.

Comment: btw, these 2 arrays are get directly from 2 tables in database (BigArray and SmallArray table). Do you think I should add extra column in smallArray table name "category_name" and insert category name to speed up performance instead do foreach loops like above ? :)

Comment: No, not a good idea :) . They are completely separate concepts. There are other ways to improve performance. If you are reading from database then the best way is join tables (on product.category_id=category.id) when you are querying.